# How to fix "Object.keys is not a function" error for Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I want to incorporate firebase to my JS game (leaderboard), and i am able to write to the database but im getting a weird error when i retrieve data, it says that Object.keys is not a function, even though im not explicitly using that function.

I've looked at other stackoverflow questions and looked up the docs to no avail.

index.html

```html
<head>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.10.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.10.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div>
    <form id="high_score" class="hidden">
       <input id="name" type="text">
       <input type="submit" id="high_score_button" >
    </form>

    <ul id="high_score_list"></ul>
</div>

<script>
        // Initialize Firebase
        var config = {
          apiKey: "#####",
          authDomain: "#####",
          databaseURL: "#####",
          projectId: "#####",
          storageBucket: "#####",
          messagingSenderId: "#####"
        };
        firebase.initializeApp(config);
        const database = firebase.database();
      </script>
</body>
```

```
game.js

function highScoreSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const data = {
        name: "asdf",
        score: 14
    }

    const ref = database.ref('scores');
    ref.on('value', gotData);
  }

  function gotData(dataw) {
    const scores = dataw.val();
  }
```

When calling the highScoreSubmit function i receive the following errors:

SyncPoint.ts:244 Uncaught TypeError: Object.keys is not a function

Comment: So where do you define `keys`? In `console.log(keys);` usage

Comment: Did you mean to do `console.log(scores);`?

Comment: sorry that was a mistake, i've corrected it, and now my function is:

Comment: function highScoreSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  
    const data = {
        name: "asdf",
        score: 14
    }

    const ref = database.ref('scores');
    ref.on('value', gotData());
  }

  function gotData(dataw) {
    const scores = dataw.val();
  }

Comment: You are calling `gotData()` directly on the `value` event. You should be passing in a reference to the function instead, i.e.: `ref.on('value', gotData);`

Comment: When i pass in the reference to the gotData function, i get hit the error: SyncPoint.ts:244 Uncaught TypeError: Object.keys is not a function

Comment: What is on line 244?

Comment: the error occurs on (SyncPoint.ts:244), which isnt on my app. i'm not quite sure where syncpoint is.